# Babel Snippets for ReactJS not working in sublime text

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I edited my key bindings because the only trigger that would work inside the editor is when I type rcc. Was hoping that when I type cdm, it will work. This is the package I installed - https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime-snippets

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+,"],
  "command": "insert_snippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "Packages/Babel Snippets/react_wrap.sublime-snippet"
  }
}
```

to this

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+shift+,"],
  "command": "insert_snippet",
  "args": {
    "name": "Packages/Babel Snippets/react_componentDidMount_(class).sublime-snippet"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who will encounter this in the future. I got it working. Part of the problem that confused me was that there was no documentation on what and how to add a snippet. There was an instruction for adding a keybinding for react_wrap. Normally when we see tons of snippet files, we would do the same thing, add config for each files.

I really didn't have to add the react_componentDidMount_(class).sublime-snippet. I was told to type cdm inside the class and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the current language selected is not `javascript` but `javascript(Babel)`. If you don't have it, just install it from package manager. It's available by the name of `Babel`

[image: babel]

Also you can set it the default language for some extensions like `.jsx`.

[image: default]